# Columns to rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one requirement to display the data total no of days for a month and Sunday's for month as shown below..

Total days : 30
Sundays : 4

Please help me on this..

I have tried below query..

```
WITH total_days AS
(
    SELECT  to_char(last_day(sysdate),'dd') total,
            (select trunc((last_day(trunc(sysdate))-(trunc(sysdate,'mm'))+1)/7) from dual) Sunday,
            1 no
    FROM Dual
)
SELECT  total,
        sunday
FROM    total_days td
pivot
(
    count(1)
    FOR no in(1)
);
```

Please help me on this..

Many thanks for your help.

I am using oracle 11g version...

Comment: I want the outpu like Total_days :30 Sundays : 4 for a particlular month...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query 1:**

```
/* A CTE with all days in current month */
with current_month_days as
(
  select trunc(sysdate,'MON')+level-1 as my_date
  from dual
  connect by level <= to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD')
)
select count(1) as total_days,
       count(decode(TO_CHAR(my_date,'DY'),'SUN',1)) as "Sundays"
FROM current_month_days;
```

**Result:**

```
TOTAL_DAYS    Sundays
---------- ----------
        30          4
```

And this fetches for All days!

**Query 2:**

```
with current_month_days as
(
  select trunc(sysdate,'MON')+level-1 as my_date 
   from dual
  connect by level <= to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD')
)
select NVL(TO_CHAR(my_date,'DAY'),'TOTAL') as day,
        count(1)
FROM current_month_days
GROUP BY ROLLUP(TO_CHAR(my_date,'DAY'));
```

**Result:**

```
DAY                                    COUNT(1)
------------------------------------ ----------
FRIDAY                                        4
MONDAY                                        5
SATURDAY                                      4
SUNDAY                                        4
THURSDAY                                      4
TUESDAY                                       5
WEDNESDAY                                     4
TOTAL                                        30
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8)

Format requested as OP:

```
/* A CTE with all days in current month */
with current_month_days as
(
  select trunc(sysdate,'MON')+level-1 as my_date
  from dual
  connect by level <= to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD')
)
select 'Total Days : '||count(1) ||'   Sundays :'||
       count(decode(TO_CHAR(my_date,'DY'),'SUN',1)) as "Result"
FROM current_month_days;
```

**Result:**

```
Result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Days : 30   Sundays :4
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply..I need the output like            Total_days : 30                                                    Sundays : 30                                                           i want generate the report like this....                          many thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravishankar..its working fine....if i want a pass a parameter...where i have to put the condition....many thanks...

Comment: @Sunitha Instead of `sysdate` pass `to_date(:MONTH,'MON')` it would default to that month in current year!